# string file path is not working c#

Tags: c#, string, path, .net

Okay I have spent an inordinate amount of time trying to solve what the posts i've read say is a simple fix.

I want to write to a file in my documents and here is my code.

```
        string st = @"C:\Users\<NAME>\Documents\Sample1.txt";

        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(st);
        file.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Sample1[0]));
        file.Close();
```

Where  is the user name. I am getting the following error

**"A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll. An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code"**

I am using Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone Development.

If anyone can point out what i am doing wrong i would be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: `DirectoryNotFoundException` ... does the directory exist on the phone?

Comment: Debug your code, figure out which directory or file is not found in your path string.

Comment: You are using desktop Windows path conventions on a phone.  That will not work, the places where you can store a file on a consumer device are very limited.  Isolated storage is the rule.  All the answers you got are tripped up by that, you didn't make it clear what phone version you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I assuming you're using the string as you've posted it. If thats the case you should use the [SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) Enum instead.

```
var st = string.format(@"{0}\Sample1.txt", 
             Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take advantage of the [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enumeration and use `Path.Combine(...)` to create a path:

```
var path = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
    "Sample1.txt");

using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    sw.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Sample1[0]));
}
```

---

Also, `StreamWriter` should be placed within a `using` statement since it is disposable.

Answer (score 0):

To get MyDocuments use:

```
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

This will return the path to MyDocuments on the host computer.

You can see a list of SpecialFolders on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

EDIT: I just noticed you were developing for Windows Phone. Read up on the other SpecialFolders on MSDN.